# How does Eclipse show the startup interface so fast

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, jvm

Java programs start slowly.

I program a JavaFX desktop software. When I double click the executable jar, it costs nearly 5 seconds to show the window. I think the JVM spends a little time to load the class.

But when I open Eclipse, the progress GUI is showed immediately. How can I do that like Eclipse? Does it use other technology to show the GUI without JVM?

Comment: The question isn't really well formulated (title): I believe it should be more like "How can I ..." with Eclipse in your question bofy. Just my opinion tho.

Comment: A typical JavaFX application does not usually take 5 seconds to show a window.  Usually, it will be able to show something in under a second on most systems.  Perhaps you are doing some CPU or I/O intensive work as part of application initialization or startup before you show the UI.  Or maybe you have very large FXML files with lots of nodes that you are displaying on the initial screen.  Hard to say what the issue with your program is without more info on it.  If you wish, you can open a new question with more details of the solution you already have which is slow (an [mcve]).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 'eclipse' executable is actually a small C program (source code is [here](https://git.eclipse.org/c/equinox/rt.equinox.framework.git/tree/features/org.eclipse.equinox.executable.feature/library)).

This reads the eclipse.ini, displays the splash screen if it is specified and then initializes the JVM using the parameters specified in the eclipse.ini and starts the main Eclipse Java code. So the JVM initialization and Java startup is done with the splash screen already displayed.

The Java code is given a reference to the splash window so it can update the progress and close the window when done.

If you write an Eclipse RCP the same code is used to start your RCP.

Comment: Thats the point when guessing things. But *if* eclipse would have a java-based splash, it would probably not be using swing or swt ;-) ... great insight ... thank you!

Comment: You're right. Thanks. Maybe I should create a C program to start my software.

Comment: JavaFx supports SplashScreens, just FYI. We use one in our Desktop application.

Comment: @Hypnic Jerk: plain Java/AWT [supports that too](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html). For a decade…

Comment: [Since Java 6 there is the command line argument](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html) `java -splash:<file name> <class name>` to display a splash screen before the JVM is initialized (similar to Eclipse).

Answer (score 2):

The secret is: which classes are used to display that "splash screen"?!

*Guessing* here: the eclipse people have fine-tuned that code. It might be possible that they use **AWT** only components there. Well, I stay corrected: they are not using *java* at all for the splash screen (see the other answer). No surprise.

Beyond that, anecdotal answer on splashing with Java: many years ago I wrote a Swing application. Of course, the customer wanted a nice splash screen, with the company logo and a progress bar; showing the amount of loaded "modules". I coded the first version using swing panels. That panel came up after 15 seconds (no SSDs back then), and 3 seconds later, 100% were reached. Solution back then: I wrote a new version that went with a **minimal** number of AWT components. In the end, that splash screen looked a little bid "less nice" - but it came up after say 3, 5 seconds.

I think I even tampered with **class loading order** to ensure that all "expensive" classes were loaded **after** I pulled the stuff required to show the splash screen.

( and in case this doesn't result in "enough delay" between "splash showing up" and "application fully loaded" ... one could simply extend the "life time" of the splash screen by simply having it sit there a bit longer. sure, you don't tell the customer about that ;-)

Comment: Eclipse doesn't use AWT for anything, it is all SWT.

Comment: How many years ago was that? Java has [direct support for such a feature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html) for ten years now.

Comment: I think we tried to get our customer on Java 5 back then :-)